# Can mind flayers survive in sunlight?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

Mind flayers are, of course, underground-dwellers, living in the underdark, far away from the sun. Entirely theoretically, though, say a mind flayer was above ground for an extended period of time - like, he abandoned his colony and set up a shop or something. Would long-term exposure to the sun damage the mind flayer's skin? I'm pretty sure that they secrete a protective mucus to keep their skin from being damaged by harsh conditions, or something like that? I mean, I know that many subterranean creatures can be damaged by extended exposure to sunlight. Let's say the mind flayer managed to obtain a steady source of humanoid brains, and as such at least wouldn't starve to death. Would exposure to sunlight shorten its life expectancy or something like that? If so, could it survive longer if it stayed inside a dark building?

Comment: You should probably specify whether you're ok with lore from other editions, or only interested in 5e material for answers to this question.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you have access to the 5e Monster Manual? Because a some of your questions seem like they have answers straight out of it.

Comment: I have downvoted this question because it shows a lack of research effort--the answer is easily found in the MM.

Comment: @CAnderson I'm... not sure what you're trying to say?

Comment: Sorry realized that might have been rude. Was demonstrating the ease of search.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Yes**

In the Monster Manual (5th Edition) there is nothing talking about sunlight sensitivity or any other weaknesses related to sunlight.